# SELECT with MySQL a specific date from a range

Tags: mysql, date-range

i've two tables

```
Table A: a_id,timemarker (datetime)

Table B: b_id,start (datetime), stop(datetime), cat(varchar)

table A

149|2010-07-19 07:43:45

150|2010-07-19 08:01:34

151|2010-07-19 07:49:12

table B

565447|2010-07-19 07:30:00|2010-07-19 08:00:00

565448|2010-07-19 08:00:00|2010-07-19 08:20:00
```

i want select all rows from Table A who are in the range of Table B

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Select any A that is within ANY [B.start, B.end]

```
select a.*
from
table a 
where exists ( select * from table b where a.timemarker between b.start and b.stop)
;
```

The OP writes

> i have trouble with my keys! the query executes very long. i have got in table a over 40k rows and in table b over 1.4 million rows... there is no relation within the tables – Norman 3 secs ago

Yes, because you're potentially comparing each A with every B = 40k * 1.4M comparisons.

But your question was "how do I do this", not "here's how I'm doing it, how can I make it faster".

if you want it faster, you'll need to add an index on B(start, end);

Comment: i have trouble with my keys! the query executes very long. i have got in table a over 40k rows and in table b over 1.4 million rows...

there is no relation within the tables

Comment: i've added the keys but still... slow...

query:

select b.* from b
where exists ( 
select * from a where a.timemarker='2010-07-19 07:44:25' 
between b.start and b.stop
)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.* FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON
  a.timemarker BETWEEN b.start AND b.end
GROUP BY a.id
```

I think this should be less expensive. Of course an extra index will help, too :)